# Node: Proper place to require database config

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

What my team has been doing: server.js requires server-config.js (Express routing, API requests, etc), which requires query.js (where my Mongoose MongoDB schema is defined) which in turn requires db-config.js (where I actually connect to Mongo). Then in my db-config I have to require the query.js Schema anyways, which creates a cyclic dependency.

Wouldn't it be better just to require db-config instead of query.js inside of server-config? That way, the database connection is started and then the cyclic dependency is broken.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail why db-config has a dependency on query.js?  If db-config offers generic methods to query MongoDB, it can be implemented independent of any schemas.

Comment: @xaviert db-config has specific query methods, but now that you mention it, shouldn't these query methods be moved into the schema and not inside db-config?